# In C#, how do inferred variables using var behave with respect to memory and lifecycle?

Tags: c#, memory-management, type-inference

Ok, I've been reading everything I can find on var, and I'm pretty sure I've got a handle on their basic behaviors and type inference. I've always been a big proponent of explicit types, so var makes me a little edgy when I'm reading code. So I have a couple of questions regarding its memory usage and the behavior of a variable declared with var over the course of that variable's lifecycle in memory.

Since var is an inference to an explicit or anonymous type, will its memory be allocated in the same place its corresponding type would be or is var universally created on the heap and accessed as if it were an object. As an example:

```
int i = 5;  // puts this on the stack
var i = 5;  // does this also go on the stack?
```

Does a declared var have a constant type once it is initialized or can it be adjusted as well? I ask this because I can't find in the documentation that specifies this, and I just read something in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128432/type-inferring-a-constant-in-c) by [@Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert):

> a variable is a storage location whose
>   contents change

Having tested the following code, I see an implicit conversion exception even at the IDE level. I don't have the experience with LINQ at this point to run a similar test with respect to anonymous types. Do they follow this same behavior? Will the IDE recognize a type mismatch at design time or would such code receive a run-time exception?

```
var i = 5;    // Initializes as int, value is 5
i = "Steve";  // Type casting error
```

Finally, is there ever a situation that you can think of where you may know a type at design time but it would be prudent to use var anyway? I ask because I've seen code samples where people do this, and from what I've read it strikes me as just lazy-coding.

EDIT: I realize there are a lot of articles talking about this topic, but I haven't found any that answer these questions specifically (though some hint one way or another). I would be happy to read any document you feel is relevant to these topics, just please post a link.

Comment: It does. It says "equivalent". Thus it should behave exactly the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`var` is 100% syntactic sugar in the C# compiler. When the actual IL is generated, the type is explicitly defined. `var`-declared variables do not behave any differently from their explicitly-defined counterparts. The dearth of information you're seeing is coming from the fact that `var` is simpler than you're assuming. There is quite literally no difference between these two lines:

```
var i = 10;
int j = 10;
```

(Other than the fact that you see the words `var` and `int`, of course; they are functionally completely identical).

Comment: @Adam - so by that rationale, if I were to diagram out anonymous types as if they had explicit names like X, Y, Z, I should reasonably be able to track how they will behave and where their memory should be allocated?

Comment: @Joel - no, you can't, but that's becuase .Net uses managed memory and so you can't track where memory is allocated anyway.  The important thing to know is the `int i = 10;` and `var i = 10;` compile to _the exact same IL_.

Comment: @Joel Etherton: @Joel Coehoorn is right; you can't do that with anonymous types, but you also can't do it with any other type. If by "where" you mean stack vs. heap, then all anonymous types are on the heap, as all anonymous types are reference types. It's not really something terribly relevant, though, as all instances of an anonymous type will fall out of scope no later than the end of the method in which they're declared, since you cannot expose an anonymous type outside of its declaring method.

Comment: @Adam, @Joel Coehoorn: Thanks. my statement really was more of me just trying to wrap my brain around the concept.

Comment: @Adam: The fact that an anonymous type cannot be directly exposed in the return type of a method at compile time has nothing whatsoever to do with the lifetime of an instance! A method is free to return object, and that object can be an instance of an anonymous type.

Comment: @Eric: That's true, I hadn't considered returning the instance as an `object`.

Comment: Or, you can extend the lifetime of an instance of anonymous type by capturing a local variable of anonymous type in a lambda, and then passing out the delegate. That way you can effectively make a field of anonymous type, since hoisted local variables are implemented as fields.

Answer (score 8):

var variables are infered by the compiler, they are really just syntactical sugar, there is no difference between:

```
var i =0;
```

and

```
int i = 0;
```

in the compiled code.

They were added for the purpose of allowing anonymous types, e.g.

```
var MyVar = new { prop1="A string", prop2=5};
```

Yes var varables recognise a type mismatch at compile time, the compiler dynamically creates a class for them when it compiles.  e.g. the below would not compile:

```
var MyVar = new { prop1="A string", prop2=5};
MyVar = "Fred";
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, `var` has no effect on how the variables behave in terms of memory - it just means you don't specify the name. For anonymous types you *couldn't* specify the name, first because you don't know it at compile time, and second because the names are deliberately "unspeakable" - they're not valid in C#. (Generally they contain `<>` for example.)

The IL generated for code using `var` and code using an explicit name is *exactly* the same. Just as a normal variable can't change type, nor can a variable declared using `var`... so in your example where you try to assign the value "Steve" to a variable which has an implicit type of `int`, you'll get a compile-time error exactly as if you'd *explicitly* declared it to be of type `int`.

As for when to use `var` and when not to, I have a few rules of thumb:

- Obviously if you want the variable to have a type other than the compile-time type of the assigned expression, you've got to do it explicitly
- For constructor calls, it's always clear what the the type is even if you're using `var`
- `var` is useful for emphasizing *what* the code is meant to do rather than *how*
- Often I use `var` if the explicit name would be extremely long - particularly for generics with multiple type arguments.

Basically it's all about readability: if the code is easier to read using `var`, go for it. If not, don't. Note that this *isn't* the same as saving typing... code is generally read more than it's written, so think about your reader. Eric Lippert wrote a great [note](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=61) when tech reviewing the first edition of C# in Depth, which is worth a read.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say var is useful for emphasizing what the code is meant to do rather than how.

Comment: @Joel: Read Eric's note, linked in the last sentence - as ever, Eric puts things better than I do.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: exactly the same as normal variables.

`var` declarations are translated into specific (strong) types at compile-timee. `var` is simply a method of automatic type inference, and has nothing to do with dynamic languages. At the end of the day, it's just the compiler being clever and translating `var` into what actual type you want.

Answer (score 1):

"Since var is an inference to an explicit or anonymous type, will its memory be allocated in the same place its corresponding type would be or is var universally created on the heap and accessed as if it were an object"

The important thing about var, is that the compiler changes the var statement to the actual type at compile time, so:

```
var number = 1;
```

Will get changed to:

```
System.Int32 number = 1;
```

...by the compiler.  And as such the memory locations for storage of these types is no different.  var is essentially syntactic sugar.  So, method local declarations of value types will get stored on the stack, reference pointers will get stored on the stack with the referenced objects on the heap.

Once you have declared a variable as var, because this is translated into its full type by the compiler, you can't then dynamically change the type:

```
var i = 5;
i = "Steve";
```

...is invalid, because its already been declared as an Int32.

Anonymous types follow a similar behaviour, where a type is created by the compiler during compilation.

"Finally, is there ever a situation that you can think of where you may know a type at design time but it would be prudent to use var anyway?"

Personally, I follow a simple pattern:

For primitives, I always put the type:

```
int i = 5;
string name = "Matt";
```

For complex types, I mostly do this:

```
var instance = new MyComplexTypeInstance();
```

For LINQ results, I stick to var:

```
var result = from i in something select i;
```

For methods, if the method is descriptive of the type being returned, then I will use var.

```
var instance = GetInstance();
```

Whereas, more complex method names, I'd put the actual type:

```
Result result = DoSomethingWeirdAndWonderful();
```

Each developer will find something they are comfortable with, the choice is yours.  As var is only really a design-time thing, its all syntactic sugar.