# Shorthand for `short` type?

Tags: c#, short

You can assign decimal values like this:

```
decimal dec = 1.0m;
```

and floats like this:

```
float flt = 1f;
```

does a similar shorthand exist for `short`? I'm asking because I'm multiplying 2 shorts and it defaults to `int` and I'm trying to avoid unnecessary casting, since I know the result will always be as small as a short anyway.

Comment: Your "shorthand" is wrong for `decimal`. It should be `1.0m`.

Comment: "and I'm trying to avoid unnecessary casting" - ? You cast when you have to cast....

Comment: @MitchWheat I don't need to cast, the answer will always be small enough to fit into a `short` anyway, that doesn't really answer my question anyway

Comment: You have to cast: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670511/how-to-specify-a-short-int-constant-without-casting

Comment: Your "unnecessary casting" would be done by the compiler, so it is equivalent to this "shorthand". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/166809/1659828

Comment: I would think that for compiler it takes longer to read extra `f` character than to cast it (and it is done at compile time anyway). In other words, just use `float flt = 1;`

Comment: @dhsto Sorry I wasn't aware this was a duplicate, I'll vote to close

Comment: @HonzaBrestan Thanks I wasn't aware that the shorthand was the equivelant to a cast

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify that it is a short value with casting.

```
s3 = (short)(s1 * s2);
```

Comment: This is because the C# pre-defined overloads for `operator *` do not include any `short operator *(short, short)` overload. So that is the technical reason why you need to cast. The "product" has type `int` because of overload resolution. __Note however:__ If you are OK with getting the result into one of the original variables, you can use `*=` which needs no cast. Example: `s1 *= s2; /* OK for shorts */`

Comment: And see also [this "integer sum blues" answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4347752/1336654).