# Cannot assign 0 to a short variable in c# from a ternary

Tags: c#, casting

I am trying to assign 0 to a short variable from a condition and it throws compile time error that

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Refer below screenshot. The salesLineInput.Discount is a `short` and SalesLineEntity.Discount is a `Nullable<double>`:

[image]

This is some other code I tried (not the same as in the screenshot):

```
    if(SalesLineEntity.Discount.HasValue)
       salesLineInput.Discount = (short)(SalesLineEntity.Discount * 100);
    else
       salesLineInput.Discount = 0;
```

Why does the `if` work, but the ternary doesn't?

Comment: Please always post code as text instead of images, so it is searchable and can be copied to reproduce the problem or quote it in answers. And since `0` is taken by the compiler as `int`, the result type of the `?` operator is `int`. You either need to cast the `0` or the whole statement to `short`

Comment: You get this compilation error because there is a mismatch between the types of both return values in the conditional statement. On one side you return a short (explicit cast), on the other hand an int. Note that you [cannot specify without casting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8670736/1507014) that 0 is indeed a short in your case. So [the answer by TheGeneral](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053780/1507014) is the right way to do it.

Comment: The simplest fix is to change your code to `salesLineInput.Discount = (short)((SalesLineEntity.Discount ?? 0) * 100);`

Comment: @mjwills Now I get it I was searching for a numeric literal suffix for the short type which isn't available. So I have to explicitly cast it. This is my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Cast* the whole *statement* to `short`

```
 salesLineItem.Discount = (short)(condition ? somecalc : 0);
```

or

```
 salesLineItem.Discount = condition ? somecalc : (short)0;
```